# How to pass URL params dynamically and get relevant data from JSON object?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I have JSON data in `home.ts` as shown below:

export class HomePage {

```
  jsonData  = {    
          "link1": "Content from link1",
          "link2":"Content from link2",
          "link3":"Content from link3"
        }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    console.log(this.jsonData);
  }
```

I simply want to pass `localhost:8100/link1` and `home.html` should show data which belongs to `link1`. Similarly for any other.

I am not aware of how to achieve this.

Comment: Well, to achieve this you have to learn about parameterized routes. Have a look at this tutorial. Her you'll find everything you need reaching your goal: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-hero-detail-route

Comment: Please clear my confusion, i dont want to navigate from one component to another, rather i will be on same `home.html` page and as per the value in the url, i want to load the data from the object. Hope this is possible